# Hstore and multitenancy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm bulding an app where users can add custom fields and submit data. I'm using Postgresql so I thought that Hstore would be the perfect solution for this. Also because it allows to query the custom data that the users may introduce. My problem is that Hstore can only be installed into one schema and I'm using apartment gem for multitenancy. So each User has one schema in the database.

The data into the Hstore column is private, so I don't want other users to get access to it. How can I acomplish this? I prefer to store this data into the same user's schema. Is there another solution?

Comment: Install the `hstore` extension in its own schema and have that always on the `search_path`. Alternately, use the JSON support in PostgreSQL 9.3/9.4.

Comment: Having Hstore into one schema and in one table, does not get slower performance than having a JSON column in every user schema? I plan having thousands of records. Which one is better? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craig is telling you to install hstore in its own schema. That means doing something along these lines.

```
create schema hs;
create extension hstore with schema hs;
```

This has *nothing* to do with how and where you store hstore *data*.

If I had a personal schema named "mike", I would build tables in the "mike" schema with hstore data types like this.

```
create schema mike;
create table mike.test (
  some_column_name hs.hstore
);
```

You can avoid having to use the "hs" schema name (as in "hs".hstore) by putting that schema in the search path. If you were doing a "normal" client/server application, you'd probably want to set it at the database level.

```
alter database your_database_name set search_path TO mike, hs, public;
```

But in your multi-tenant architecture, which has one schema per tenant, you'd *probably* want one database role per tenant, and you'd *probably* want to set the search path for each role. (I'm not familiar with the "apartment" gem; I presume it creates one role per tenant and one schema per tenant. Verify that by checking the database schema.)

```
alter role one_role_name set search_path to one_role_name, hs, public;
```

I'd also want to verify sensible privileges on the schemas. For example, in a multi-tenant architecture like yours, I'd want to verify that only "mike" has privileges in the "mike" schema.

The first schema in the search path becomes the default schema for new objects. On the other hand, database objects in that schema can hide database objects of the same name in other schemas. Keep that in the back of your mind.

Finally, thousands of rows is a tiny database. Performance problems will probably have nothing to do with your database search path.

Comment: A very good answer. My confusion was that if I install hstore into one schema, I have to use that schema only for the hstore data. Apartment gem only creates a schema per Tenant. Thank you!